# How to track cursor in Android Calculator App?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I'm trying to design a calculator app in Android to learn Java and Android at the same time but I do have prior experience with C++.

So far I've got two TextView elements. One displays the answer and one displays the input. However I don't want to use the user keyboard. I want to have my own buttons that navigate the input field. This is pretty standard for calculator apps.

If the user puts in 3+45/2.45*tan(9) that is put into a string array that would read
{3, +, 45, /, 2.45, *, tan, (, 9, )}. This is then validated, and processed by an RPN function when the user pushes equals.

Now this displays all nice, however I can't figure out how to implement a backspace or arrow keys that would navigate this input TextView field. I need to know where the cursor is which I'm not sure can even be enabled with TextView. Do I need to switch over to EditView? I want functionality so the cursor would skip over functions with one arrow push and delete functions with one push of delete but still navigate non-functions with single presses. For example, when pushing backspace on tan, it should delete all of tan, and not just leave "ta".

Any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Cursor position using the getSelectionStart() and getSelectionEnd() methods. If no text is highlighted, both getSelectionStart() and getSelectionEnd() return the position of the cursor.

Also, take a look at TextWatcher class. Its what Android uses, for per example, auto-formatting/adjusting phone numbers while typing etc.

Here you can find a list of TextWatchers used in Android to give you an idea; 
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/android/2.2.1/android/text/TextWatcher.java

Comment: Thank you this has led me on the right path. The phone number code is very similar to the behaviour I'm looking for! I'd upvote you if I could...